# Textarea grow with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im doing a little comment feature for a business app.
Each comment is a span if you click on it it changes into a textarea

Problem is that I want the textarea to take the same amount of space as the text in it (like the span when not editing)

I have found solutions that let rows grow with text (jQuery Autosize etc) but are there any solution that let both width and height grow with the text?

**edit:** In its editmode the markup looks something like this (Using Knockout so this is how the dynamic rendered HTML looks like, the actual KO html is different)

```
<li>
    <span style="display: none">This is a comment</span>
    <textarea>This is a comment</textarea>
    <span class="username">UserOne</span>
    <span class="timestamp">Mars 26 '13</span>
</li>
```

**edit2:** So this is the only solution:
Set cols to the longest line in the textarea and set max width of text-area to parent-width minus total sibbling width? No cleaner out of the box solution for this using CSS or jQuery?

Comment: How would the computer know which to constrain, if both width and height may grow?

Comment: sorry thats a good question that i forgot, it shouldn't grow more then that it self and its inline siblings can fit inside the parents width

Comment: Height is unrestricted

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dynamically resize the height of textarea on keyup and keydown. Assign the height to auto so that the scrollHeight reflects the height needed and then reassign height to it. Check out the following code :

```
        var computedElement = window.getComputedStyle($(element)[0]),
        paddingTop = parseInt(computedElement.paddingTop),
        paddingBottom = parseInt(computedElement.paddingBottom),
        borderBottom = parseInt(computedElement.borderBottom),
        borderTop = parseInt(computedElement.borderTop),
        lineHeight = parseInt(computedElement.lineHeight),
        outerHeight = paddingBottom + paddingTop + borderTop + borderBottom;

        var resize = function() {
          //height:auto resets the height to row=1 to get the scrollHeight without white space
          $(element).css('height', 'auto');
          $(element).height($(element)[0].scrollHeight - outerHeight);
        }

        //first resize to set the existing text
        $timeout(function(){
          if($(element).val().length) {
            resize();
          }
        });

        //resize on keyup and keydown 
        $(element).on('keydown keyup', function() {
          $timeout(function(){
            resize();
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div[contenteditable]{
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: none;
}
</style>


<div contenteditable>Type me</div>
```